# Set phpBB http status code for deleted sites

Tags: http-status-code-301, http-status-codes, phpbb, http-status-code-403

I need to set the html status codes for a phpBB forum. Google Webmaster Toolkit shows a lot of wrong status codes and this is bad for SEO and for usability.

I've searched a lot but cannot find any appropriate answer. Maybe someone can help me an tell me if theres a way in phpBB or if there's a plugin to achieve this.

The status codes should be different depending on:

- User/Thread has been deleted => Status Code "410" (Gone)
- Thread has been moved => Status Code "301" (Moved Permanently)
- Site can only be seen when logged in => Status Code "403" (Forbidden)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, for those who might have the same need, here is the solution.

Reading this [PhpBB Tracker](http://tracker.phpbb.com/browse/PHPBB3-7782)  issue I found this [git commit](https://github.com/naderman/phpbb3/commit/c185e45e09032e3ac32149a91f0133deb425acaa) which lead me to this solution.
Patch the file /path_to_yout_phpbb_forum/includes/functions.php

```
//line 2618-2637
function send_status_line($code, $message)
{
        if (substr(strtolower(@php_sapi_name()),0,3) === 'cgi')
        {
        // in theory, we shouldn't need that due to php doing it. Reality offers a differing opinion, though
        header("Status: $code $message", true, $code);
        }
        else
        {
           if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_VERSION']))
           {
               $version = $_SERVER['HTTP_VERSION'];
            }
            else
            {
               $version = 'HTTP/1.0';
            }
            header("$version $code $message", true, $code);
        }
}
```

and

```
//line 3654-3657
if ($msg_text == 'ERROR_NO_ATTACHMENT' || $msg_text == 'NO_FORUM' || $msg_text == 'NO_TOPIC' || $msg_text == 'NO_USER')
{
    send_status_line(404, 'Not Found');
}
```

This worked for my problem.